# How to configure App.js in react-native to use React-native-ui-kitten?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli, react-native-ui-kitten

I am a newbie in react-native and I'm trying to use the `react-native-ui-kitten` library. The problem is that the documentation is not really helpful.

I have I have installed `ui-kitten` and the theme as indicated with the command: `npm i react-native-ui-kitten @eva-design/eva`

The documentation asks to configure the application root which I consider to be the `App.js` file unless I'm wrong.

So i changed the `App.js` generated code to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  mapping,
  theme,
} from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import { Application } from './path-to/root.component';

export default class App extends React.Component {

   public render(): React.ReactNode {
     return (
       <ApplicationProvider
         mapping={mapping}
         theme={theme}>
         <Application/>
       </ApplicationProvider>
     );
   }
}
```

Unfortunetely it's not working.

Has anyone recently used `ui-kitten` library ?

What does the documentation mean by Application Root and how to set up a simple react-native project to use `react-native-ui-kitten`?

And yes I actually checked the documentation but maybe there is something I am not doing right.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.
I discovered that the creators of this UI kit use in fact in their code examples Typescript.
So you need to recreate your Reactnative project using a Typescript template, then rename accordingly the App.js into App.tsx
Any other components need to be renamed with the extension .tsx. 
Make sure you read about Typescript:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org

Here it is how you can recreate your project with Typescript:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native

All the best,

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner in react-native and it seems we kinda differ in implementing the code. I am not sure if this would help but this is the way I implement your code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mapping, light as lightTheme } from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import { Application } from './path-to/root.component';

const App = () => (
    <ApplicationProvider
        mapping={mapping}
        theme={lightTheme}>
        <Application/>
    </ApplicationProvider>
);

export default App;
```

You could try it and let me know if this suits you. Good luck!